# accessing element in an openCV homography matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, element, homography

I have a 3x3 homography matrix , which I computed using findHomography() function.
I store it in a cv::Mat matrix.

I am trying to do element access using the following code

```
float cvHomography::accessElements(const cv::Mat& aCvMat)
{
    //cout << aCvMat << endl;

    const float* Mi;
    for( int i = 0; i < aCvMat.rows; i++){
        Mi = aCvMat.ptr<float>(i);
        for( int j = 0; j < aCvMat.cols; j++){
            cout << Mi[j] << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

The above does not return the correct value from the homography matrix.
I have searched through documentation , tutorials and google and I honestly cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work (if you are sure that type of the image is CV_64F):

```
void cvHomography::accessElements(const cv::Mat& aCvMat)
{
    // assert aCvMat.type() == CV_64F
    for( int i = 0; i < aCvMat.rows; i++){
        for( int j = 0; j < aCvMat.cols; j++){
            cout << aCvMat.at<double>(i,j) << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Also an overloaded operator << for std::ostream works with cv::Mat if you would like just to display image elements.

Comment: how can I be sure about the type of the matrix. openCv documentation does not state the type of the return matrix :(

Comment: @maroi. I tried the method, but I still get the wrong value. 
Also, no it's not just the `cout` I want to do. What I am curious about is the fact that the overloaded `<<` operator , prints the correct matrix. so if the aCvMat is correct, why would the `.at<T>()` send back wrong data?

Comment: ok it is a `<double>` after all. not a `<float>`. please update your answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: Ok, now it is double.

Comment: The type of a matrix can be checked by calling the type() function, which is part of the cv::Mat class. It returns a constant value, defined as a macro somewhere OpenCV's source code. An overview can be seen at http://docs.opencv.org/java/constant-values.html#org.opencv.core.CvType . Just print out the result that type() returns and compare it to the numbers in the table.